# Pika asynchronous publisher in a thread

Tags: python-3.x, pika

I followed the [Asynchronous publisher example](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.html) from pika and tried to run its `self._connection.ioloop.start()` in a separate thread. So far I managed to use a queue for the main thread to add messages to publish. But the only way I could get the publisher thread to get the messages from the queue is not satisfactory. I used something like

```
try:
    message = self._queue.get(True, 1)
    self._channel.basic_publish(body=message, exchange=self._exchange, routing_key='example.text')
except queue.Empty:
    pass
finally:
    self._connection.add_timeout(0.0001, self.publish_message)
```

There has to be a better way to do this, right? It's important to note that I'm using this with Python 3.6.4 in **Windows** and the IO loop chosen by `pika.SelectConnection` seems to be very limited...

Edit: I just found out how to use `adapters.AsyncioConnection` instead of `SelectConnection`. So now I can replace `self._connection.add_timeout(0.0001, self.publish_message)` with `self._connection.loop.call_soon(self.publish_message)`. 
This gives very weird results: messages seems to be buffered and sent every seconds. I'm new to Python so I would appreciate some insight at lot!

Comment: Please provide a repository with full working examples. You say "get the messages from the queue" but I don't see any code that actually consumes messages.

Comment: Here is an updated example: https://pastebin.com/wcb5vsZZ. `self._queue.get(True, 1)` is where the queue is consumed.

Comment: I see that was confusing: I was talking about and inter-thread queue, not a broker queue...

Comment: @Syranolic, https://pastebin.com/wcb5vsZZ is removed. Can you share the correct link?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that. In fact I don't use pika anymore. I use aio-pika now. I'm afraid this old question has become more misleading than helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to this question, in case it still comes up in search results, is to upgrade to at least Pika v0.12 and take advantage of the method *add_callback_threadsafe* available for various connection adapters. [Here](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.12.0/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py) is an example.